# How to generate more than one unique random number, using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to generate more than one unique random number, using Javascript ?

i know of this javascript,

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1) + ',' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1) + ',' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) +1)
```

but it replicates the number.
for example, 3,1,1 may be a result.
I need to generate 3 unique random numbers. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You have to check if the number that's been generated was previously generated. Hint: That means having knowledge of previously generated random numbers stored somewhere.

Comment: If duplication is not allowed then the resulting set isn't really random, ;)

Comment: fair point. but this is step 1 of what i need. 3 unique numbers to display..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var temp = 0,
    results = [];

do {
   // generate random number
    temp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

    // see if number has already been generated
    if (!results.includes(temp)) {
        // it has not, so add it
        results.push(temp);
    }
} while (results.length < 3);
```

** Not supported in IE before Edge 14 but there is a polyfill

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any polyfills you can just take the old indexOf style

```
function getNumber(){
   return Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)
}

var numbers = [];
do {
  var rnd = getNumber();
  if (numbers.indexOf(rnd) == -1){
    numbers.push(rnd);
  }
}
while (numbers.length < 3)
```

Comment: what is the javascript for this function?

Comment: What do you mean? It's plain old Javascript.

Comment: It doesn't even use anything from ES5.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps you:

```
function GRN()
{
    var availableNumbers = [1,2,3];
    var result = [];
        for (var i = 0;i < 3;i++)
        {
            var ix = Math.round(Math.random() * (availableNumbers.length - 1));
            result.push(availableNumbers[ix]);
            availableNumbers.splice(ix,1);
        }
    return result;
}
```

The GRN function returns three unique random numbers in an array.